# Can't switch camera WebRTC angular on browser in android devices

Tags: angular, webrtc, angular17

I I'm actually having a very confusing problem with my project. Building and running Webrtc is fine on iOS devices, but when used on Android phones, while making video calls, changing cameras cannot be done, when pressing cam recording it, the video stream will be black and the interface will freeze. Even if the script runs afterwards, it will not change the interface[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS7U8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoBt6.png)

I tried many things with many libraries but it didn't work